# (Renormalized) Stress Tensor in Di Francesco et al

Tags: renormalization, conventions, conformal-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

in Chapter 5.2 regarding the Ward identities the authors introduce a renormalized energy-momentum tensor

$$T=-2\pi T_{zz}, \hspace{2cm} \bar{T}=-2\pi T_{\bar{z}\bar{z}}\hspace{2cm} (5.40)$$

What is the motivation for this redefinition? I am also confused because later in the chapter, where they relate the energy of the plane with the one of the cylinder, they write

$$\langle T_{cyl.}(w)\rangle=-\frac{c \pi^2}{6 L^2} \hspace{5cm} (5.139)$$

while a few lines after

$$\langle T^{00} \rangle= \langle T_{zz}\rangle + \langle T_{\bar{z}\bar{z}}\rangle=-(1/\pi)\langle T \rangle =\frac{c \pi}{6 L^2} \hspace{1cm} (5.141)$$

I am confused about the sign difference. Which one now is the physical energy density? I thought that it is given by $T^{00}$, but also I thought it was negative for the cylinder (as for the plate scenario). Help is much appreciated!